# Linear dependency for a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\3 & 4  \end{pmatrix}$$ and I want to find the smallest value of $n$ such that $I, A, A^1, A^2, ..., A^n$ are linearly dependent.

Other than pure brute force, I am not sure how to tackle this question.

I reckon there is a much more simpler method that I am overlooking and would appreciate help being pointed in that direction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ever heard of Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: I have heard of this, not too sure what it is, but I don't think it's in our course...

Comment: It says that $P(A)=0$ for the polynom $P(x)=det(A-xI)$ thus a relationship of degree $2$ between $I$ and $A$.

Comment: ok but i am not sure how to use that to find n

Comment: @Wojowu It is the theory of minimal polynomial which is the most appropriate.

Comment: @JeanMarie I am aware of that. Cayley-Hamilton theorem gives a very useful upper bound on the degree of minimal polynomial.

Comment: @zwim how does the theorem imply a relationship of degree 2

Comment: A matrix is a root of its minimal polynomial, which has degree the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: @Wojowu My bad, I realize now that we are with $2 \times 2$ matrices, thus if the minimal polynomial had degree 1 instead of 2, it would mean that the matrix is a multiple of identity matrix I, wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will be difficult to provide an answer easier than the one by mvw, but either way I would like to showcase how Cayley-Hamilton theorem can be used here.

Cayley-Hamilton theorem states that, for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, we have $P(A)=0$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial which, for numbers $x$ is defined via $P(x)=\det(xI_n-A)$. Note that this polynomial has degree equal to $n$ (which is seen immediately from the Leibniz formula for the determinant).

Therefore, in this problem, $P(A)=0$, where $P(x)$ is some polynomial of degree $2$, say $x^2+ax+b$. But look what happens when we plug $x=A$ in - we get $A^2+bA+c=0$, so $A^2,A,I$ are linearly dependent.

This way we can figure out a linear dependence relation between the matrices which doesn't involve any guessing. In this problem we also have to verify that $A,I$ aren't linearly dependent, but it is easy to do.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this. This makes me smile because of its essence. Thanks!! I don't think I can rep, but if I could, this would get lots!!

Comment: Well written !...

Answer (score 1):

$$
A^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & 10 \\
15 & 22
\end{pmatrix}
= 5 A + 2 I
$$

Answer (score 0):

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

We start by calculating its characterictic polynomial, it is

$\chi (x)=\det(A-xI)=\begin{vmatrix} 1-x & 2 \\3 & 4-x \end{vmatrix}=(1-x)(4-x)-6=x^2-5x-2$

The theorem of Cayley-Hamilton says that $\chi(A)=0$ so $A^2=5A+2I$.

Is it the minimal $n$ ?

Note that $\alpha I+\beta A=0\iff (\alpha,\beta)=0$ or $A=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}I$ which is not the case, so $I,A$ are linearly independant.

> So $n=2$ is the minimal and the relation is $A^2=5A+2I$

The theorem of Cayley-Hamilton thus always give a relationship of degree $n=\dim E$ between $I$ and $A$ (or equivalently $I,A,A^2,...,A^n$ are always linearly dependant).

But $\dim E$ is not necessarily the minimal $n$, in fact the minimal polynomial that annulates for $A$ is called, guess what... the minimal polynomial $\mu(x)$, and it is a divisor of the characteristic polynomial $\chi(x)$, with the supplementary constraint that it should annulate for any of the eigenvalues of $A$, but this is maybe too much theory.

In any case, let's look at another exemple, with $\dim E=3$ this time.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 9 & 3 \\-4 & 10 & 2 \\ 2 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

Again we start with its characterictic polynomial

$\chi(x)=\begin{vmatrix} -2-x & 9 & 3 \\-4 & 10-x & 2 \\ 2 & -3 & 3-x \end{vmatrix}=48-40x+11x^2-x^3$

So we know that $A^3=11A^2-40A+48I$ so $I,A,A^2,A^3$ are linearly dependant.

Is $n=3$ the minimum ? We will see...

Notice that $\chi(x)=(4-x)^2(3-x)$ so eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{3,4\}$, yet $4$ has greater multiplicity than $1$, so it is possible that a smaller polynomial annulates for $A$.

We search for the value of the minimal polynomial, since $\mu(x)$ should annulate for each of the eignenvalues, there are only two possibilities :

$\mu(x)=\chi(x)\quad$ or $\quad\mu(x)=(x-3)(x-4)=x^2-7x+12$

So let's calculate $A^2-7A+12I$

$A^2=\begin{pmatrix} -26 & 63 & 21 \\-28 & 58 & 14 \\ 14 & -21 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$

$A^2-7A=\begin{pmatrix} -26+14 & 63-63 & 21-21 \\-28+28 & 58-70 & 14+14 \\ 14-14 & -21+21 & 9-21 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -12 & 0 & 0 \\0 & -12 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -12 \end{pmatrix}=-12I$

> So $n=2$ is the minimal and the relation is $A^2=7A-12I$

To tackle this kind of problem, first seach for the characteristic polynomial, it gives an upper bound on $n$ which is $\dim E$.

Then for try all possible values for $\mu(x)$ [as a divisor of $\chi(x)$ + it should also contains all $(x-\lambda_i)$ factors where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue in $\mathbb C$, or else consider quadratic factors in $\mathbb R$] starting from the one with all single roots and raising in degree, calculate $\mu(A)$, if it annulates you've found it.